# How to use SecureRandom with switches in Java

Tags: java, switch-statement, secure-random

Okay, so I want to use this random number generator to output one case, instead it spits out all of them, what am I doing wrong?

```
SecureRandom goodNumber = new SecureRandom();
int good = 1+ goodNumber.nextInt(4);

switch(good){
    case 1:
            System.out.println("Test1");
    case 2:
            System.out.println("Test2");
    case 3:
            System.out.println("Test3");
    case 4:
            System.out.println("Test4");

}
System.out.println(good);
}
}
```

Now the output might look like:

Test2

Test3

Test4

2

And instead, I just want it to randomly output one string

Comment: you need to `break` after each `case`

Comment: That fixed it a little, it will still output "Test2" followed by a "2". How would i make it only output the string and not the int?

Comment: @Forrest Obviously, you shouldn't do `System.out.println(good)` if you don't want to print that value.